# How to update quantities for items in a Shopping Cart?

Tags: php, html

I have created a shopping cart using sessions to store the product id, I am able to add the items to the cart but I now want to update the quantities using a session variable which keeps track of the quantities based on the product id.

I am storing the products in an array, like so.

```
$products = array(
    array("name" => "Sledgehammer", "price" => 125.75),
    array("name" => "Axe", "price" => 190.50),
    array("name" => "Bandsaw", "price" => 562.13),
    array("name" => "Chisel", "price" => 12.90),
    array("name" => "Hacksaw", "price" => 18.45),
);
```

Below is how I am currently adding to the shopping cart.

```
    $pid = (isset($_GET['pid'])) ? $_GET['pid']: "";
    if($pid != "")
    {
        if($_SESSION['shoppingCart'] == "")
        {
            $_SESSION['shoppingCart'] = array($products[$pid]); 
            $_SESSION['quantity'] = array();        
        }
        else if($_SESSION['shoppingCart'] != "")
        {

            $copyCart = $_SESSION['shoppingCart'];
            if(array_key_exists($pid, $copyCart))
            {
                //increase quantity
                $_SESSION['quantity'][$pid]++;  
            }
            else 
            {
                //new item
                array_push($_SESSION['shoppingCart'], $products[$pid]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I am getting the quantities to display in the shopping cart.

```
if($_SESSION['shoppingCart'] != '')
```

{

```
foreach($_SESSION['shoppingCart'] as $key => $value)
{   
    $name = $value['name'];
    $price = $value['price'];
    if(empty($_SESSION['quantity'][$key]))
    {
        $_SESSION['quantity'][$key] = 1;
        $qty = $_SESSION['quantity'][$key];
    }
    else
    {
        $qty = $_SESSION['quantity'][$key]; 
    }

    //new element
    echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td><td>".$price."</td><td>".$qty."</td></tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='?action=removeItem&pid=".$key."'>Remove from Cart</a></td>";     
}
```

}

If I attempt to add the last item in the product list first, it adds the item as a new item each time before updating it's quantity after being added 4 times. Mind you there are only 5 items in the product list. The issue is that, the item is added as a new item each time based on the position in the array, for example. The second last item will add 3 times first before having its quantity updated and then the third item will add itself twice before updating and so on. However the first item in the product list, adds perfectly.

I want to update the quantities every time I add an item to the cart.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What is the issue / error? put the echo statements in the code and debug the issue.

Comment: If I add the last item in the product list first, it adds the item 4 times first having a quantity of 1 and then the fifth item updates the quantity. E.g Knife $5.60 and a quantity of 1 four times first before updating the quantity to Knife $5.60 1,2,3,4,5. If that makes sense. I'll try to add a picture.

Comment: @NitinDhomse did you manage to find out?